# Internal/External Header Separation

Tags: c++

I've built a library that's layed out like this:

```
lib/
   private_class_impl.cc
   private_class_decl.h
   public_class_impl.cc
include/mylib/
             public_class_decl.h
```

My public class needs to have a private pointer to the private class.

Is there any way to expose `private_class_decl.h` to my declaration of `public_class_decl.h` without moving `private_class_decl.h` to `include/mylb/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward declare the private class in your public header (it will not expose its interface or public members).

### In public_class_decl.h

```
struct private_class;
class public_class {
    private_class *m_private;
    /* ... */
};
```

### In public_class_impl.cpp

```
#include "public_class_decl.h"
#include "private_class_decl.h"

public_class::foo() {
    // private_class interface is known since we can include
    // "private_class_decl.h" here...
    m_private->method_of_private_class();
}
```

This trick works because `public_class` uses a pointer to `private_class` which is a complete type even though we only provided a forward declaration. You cannot use `private_class` by value like the following:

```
struct private_class;
class public_class {
    private_class m_private;
    /* ... */
};
```

This would result in the error: `error: field 'm_member' has incomplete type 'private_class'`

Answer (score 1):

You can just forward declare the private class as in the [pImpl idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29)